# What's wrong with the following latex code?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The code following made me crazy.I want to use tikz to made a picture with fill color,but the output picture  has some areas without filling color.
I think it's maybe a question about the filling rule in tikz.
Windows 7;texlive 2021;pdflatex compiler is included in texlive 2021.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[fill=green](0,0)--(1,1)--(2,0) circle(0.9)--(3,1) circle(0.9)--(4,0)--(2,-0.3)--(0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: Try `\filldraw[fill=green](0,0)--(1,1)--(2,0)--(3,1)--(4,0)--(2,-0.3)--cycle (2,0) circle(0.9) (3,1) circle(0.9);`.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to draw and fill separately.